# Datagrid focus for second column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, prism

I have used datagrid with two columns 
1st column is Label
2nd column is textbox 
I want to focus on textbox when tab is pressed,Now it places focus on Label as well which i do not want.Can someone suggest a solution for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="Lable">
      <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

This will works fine. In Case if it doent, try with `DataTemplate` for Lable and set the `Focusable` to `False`.